# Potential to confuse email messaging system when replying

Tags: bug, jobs, email

I replied to an email message I received through the StackOverflow Careers site this morning. Instead of posting my message above:

```
--- Reply above this line ---
```

I replied below the line. Many people do this when replying to a series of questions from the sender.

The result was the message showed up in my StackOverflow Inbox as being sent from the original sender. In other words, I was able to make it appear as though the original sender sent me an email, with whatever content I wanted to add, by replying below `--- Reply above this line ---`.

This makes it possible to create messages that appear to come from the original sender.

In the screenshot below I sent the first message (Aug 24), Jack replied (Aug 25) and I sent the final message (shown as coming from Jack).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The dev responsible for reply-by-e-mail is on holiday, currently, but I will mention this upon their return. No guarantees that anything will be changed just yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to make it appear as though the original sender sent me an
>   email, with whatever content I wanted to add, by replying below

I cannot comment for Stack Exchange and if they want to address this particular situation, but faking emails is not hard.

It takes seconds to spoof an email address, even senders IP if you are that bothered, and make an email appear to have come from anyone and anywhere.

I'm not sure what problem is present from the "bug" you have raised, as the email is sent from yourself to yourself. Anyone using the system maliciously would still need to know someone else's email address, and if they have your email address then such "spoofing" can be done without the use of this "bug" through Stack Overflow.

Beyond that in terms of it being a "bug" then this is just how this emailing system works. Stack Overflow's system takes everything *below* the line as the original message - so by-design. Not sure what could be done about it really.

Comment: True, spoofing emails isn't hard, but it also shouldn't be this easy. It seems trivial to know that I replied to an email and display it properly in the inbox. In my case the message is displaying in my SE inbox as having come from the original sender (but I wrote the content). Imagine if spoofing an email in Gmail or another major email platform was as easy as replying below the original sender's message.

Comment: I added a screenshot to explain.